# Bitcoins not showing up in MultiBit after backup import

Tags: multibit, lost-bitcoins

I was using MultiBit (old version), which I've moved to
USB and moved back after a while. In between, I'd done a system recovery (Win 7 64-bit).

I reset the blockchain but still can't see the coins that
I know are still there. I had 2 wallet backups therefore
2 wallets, and it has to be in one of them. So where'd they go?

Comment: Seems as though this is not a very helpful forum....

Comment: It's utterly unclear what your quesiton is supposed to be about. It you think what you're looking for is in either one of 2 wallet backups, go check them. We can't do it for you.

Comment: You don't think I already looked in all those ? I'll tell you what you can do for me, and that's keep quiet if you have nothing useful to add.

Comment: Please provide sufficient information for other users to get an understanding of what you've been trying to do. Some things that you may want to explain: What did you do when you moved MultiBit to USB and back? What do you mean with "reset the blockchain"? Did any errors occur when you imported the backups? Have you tried importing the backups into a new version of MultiBit? Did you find any historic transactions that showed that the money ever entered the wallet?…

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you've done is too brief and it's not possible for us to tell you what went wrong.

These possible problems come to mind:

- The backups you made don't include the data you're looking for. A third state that actually held the relevant private keys was lost.
- You didn't copy the wallet data when you moved the MultiBit client to USB storage.
- You made a mistake importing the backup.
- Your bitcoins were stolen and you didn't notice.
- There is an issue with MultiBit.
- You didn't wait until MultiBit actually synchronized with the network.